# I'm new to databases and trying to get used to them using Flask- SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying the understand a few concepts from the following website: 
[Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html.). Can anyone explain me what does this command exactly do?

`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'`

I understand that it is configuring the database at some location, but I am not able to understand the syntax of the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy docs devote an entire section to describing [connection strings](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#database-urls).

```
dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
```

For your SQLite database, that would be:

```
dialect = sqlite
driver = <not required, using the default sqlite driver>
username, password, host, port: not used for sqlite
database = /tmp/test.db
```